# jQuery + PHP HighChart not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

Hopefully somebody can be of assistance. I have a jQuery chart (using HighCharts) and I use PHP to populate it with data, I initially pull in 30 records which works fine. I then want the latest record to be added every second so I have set up the setInterval option. Whilst this appears to work the latest record is not added, the last record when the chart loaded is added every second making me believe the PHP is not "refreshing".

This is probably something obvious and I have probably spent too much time looking at it and am missing the point completely.

```
<script>

$('#graph-visual').highcharts({
    chart : {
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFF0",
        type: 'line',

        events : {
            load : function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];

                setInterval(function () {


                    <?php

                        // Get Last entry only

                        include "db-conn.php";

                        $query =  "SELECT * FROM `cl50-iotdb`.`temperature_values` ";
                        $query .= "WHERE time_added IN (select max(time_added) from temperature_values GROUP BY entry_id)";
                        $query .= " ORDER BY time_added DESC LIMIT 1;";

                        $select_latest_temperature = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


                        if(!$select_latest_temperature)
                        {
                            echo "DB Connection Error";
                            die();
                        }


                        // Clear Var to ensure fresh data
                        unset($latest_temp);

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_latest_temperature))
                        {
                            $latest_temp = $row['temperature'];
                        } 

                    ?>

                    series.addPoint([<?php echo $latest_temp?>]);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    title : {
        text : 'Latest Temperature Readings'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
           text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series : [{
        name : 'Arduino Data',
        data : (function () {


                <?php

                // Get last 30 entries

                include "db-conn.php";

                $query =  "SELECT temperature, time_added FROM `cl50-iotdb`.`temperature_values` ";
                $query .= "WHERE time_added IN (select max(time_added) from temperature_values GROUP BY entry_id)";
                $query .= " ORDER BY time_added DESC LIMIT 30;";

                $select_temperature = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                if(!$select_temperature)
                {
                    echo "DB Connection Error";
                    die();
                }

                // Clear Arrays to ensure fresh data
                unset($temperatureArray);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_temperature))
                {
                    $temperatureArray[] = $row['temperature'];
                } 

                ?>

                var data = [
                            <?php 
                                foreach (array_reverse($temperatureArray) as $temp)
                                {
                                    echo $temp . ", "; 
                                } 
                            ?>
                           ]

            return data;

        }())
    }]



});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The client side JavaScript will not  what is going on in the server side PHP. So you will not be able to use set interval to call PHP code.  You will have to use your set interval to invoke an ajax function to navigate to a a php file that will return the data. Then you can output the data returned in your ajax callback to the screen.

Comment: @LarryLane Thanks, that does make a lot of sense. Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: I am going to put together a basic example. You will probably have to re arrange some parts to suit your application.

Comment: @LarryLane Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know how to do a database dump in mysql so I can reconstruct an example for you?  If you can send it to me through my website at http://bytewarestudios.com.

Comment: I am afraid I haven't done one of those before. If you could point in the right direction of constructing the AJAX call and utilising that data alongside the structure of the called file that would be very helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104733/discussion-between-larry-lane-and-torrm).

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the solution, as Larry suggested in the comments, was to use AJAX. For future reference, in order to get it to work correctly I changed the following:

The chart element was changed to use AJAX which called the PHP,

```
chart : {
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFF0",
        type: 'line',

        events : {
            load : function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];

                setInterval(function () 
                    {
                        $.ajax(
                            {  
                            type: "GET",
                            url: 'includes/get-latest-temp-graph.php',
                            success: function(NewTemp) 
                            {
                                series.addPoint([NewTemp],true, true);
                            },
                            cache: false
                        });
                    }, 2000);
            }
        }
    },
```

and the PHP that was originally in the chart element was moved to its own file,

```
<?php

// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");

// Get Last entry only

include "db-conn.php";

$query =  "SELECT * FROM `cl50-iotdb`.`temperature_values` ";
$query .= "WHERE time_added IN (select max(time_added) from temperature_values GROUP BY entry_id)";
$query .= " ORDER BY time_added DESC LIMIT 1;";

$select_latest_temperature = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


if(!$select_latest_temperature)
{
    echo "DB Connection Error";
    die();
}


// Clear Var to ensure fresh data
unset($latest_temp);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_latest_temperature))
{
    $latest_temp = $row['temperature'];
} 

echo $latest_temp;
?>
```

The above two changes fixed the problem and it now updates automatically every two seconds based on new data in the database. Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

I did some re arranging of your code to make all of the rendering of your chart a result of ajax calls and to remove the php from you JavaScript code. The code in your answer works great. If you want a more seperation of concerns approach then give my solution a try.

index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>High Charts with Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>


         <!--high charts data-->
        <div id="graph-visual"></div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/tempchart.js"></script>     


</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Service(file path js/services/tempservice.js):

```
(function($){

    //call the tempService
    TempService();


   function TempService(){//begin temp service


            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: 'services/firsttemps.php',
                        success: function (data)
                        {



                            //split data returned into an array of strings
                            var firstTemps = data.split(",");

                            //convert firstTemps to numbers
                            for (var i = 0; i < firstTemps.length; i++) {

                                //convert each string to number using the + operator
                                firstTemps[i] = +firstTemps[i];

                            }

                            //create new chart object
                            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

                                chart: {
                                    backgroundColor: "#FFFFF0",
                                    type: 'line',
                                    renderTo: "graph-visual"

                                 },

                                title: {
                                    text: 'Latest Temperature Readings'
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                                    }
                                },
                                exporting: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                series: {
                                    name: "Arduino Data",
                                    data: []

                                }
                            });


                            chart.addSeries({
                                name: "Arduino Data",
                                data: firstTemps
                            });



                            window.setInterval(function ()
                            {
                                $.ajax(
                                        {
                                            type: "GET",
                                            url: 'services/latesttemp.php',
                                            success: function (latest)
                                            {

                                                //add the lastest temp to the chart
                                                chart.series[0].addPoint([latest],true,true);

                                            },
                                            cache: false
                                        });
                            }, 2000);



                        },
                        cache: false
                    });


   }//end temp service

})(jQuery);
```

PHP files inside of a folder named services:

firsttemps.php

```
        <?php

        // Get last 30 entries

        include "db-conn.php";

        $query =  "SELECT temperature, time_added FROM `cl50-iotdb`.`temperature_values` ";
        $query .= "WHERE time_added IN (select max(time_added) from temperature_values GROUP BY entry_id)";
        $query .= " ORDER BY time_added DESC LIMIT 30;";

        $select_temperature = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(!$select_temperature)
        {
            echo "DB Connection Error";
            die();
        }

        // Clear Arrays to ensure fresh data
        unset($temperatureArray);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_temperature))
        {
            $temperatureArray[] = $row['temperature'];
        } 


        //echo data for the ajax call
        echo implode(",",$temperatureArray);


       ?>
```

latesttemp.php

```
<?php

// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");

// Get Last entry only

include "db-conn.php";

$query =  "SELECT * FROM `cl50-iotdb`.`temperature_values` ";
$query .= "WHERE time_added IN (select max(time_added) from temperature_values GROUP BY entry_id)";
$query .= " ORDER BY time_added DESC LIMIT 1;";

$select_latest_temperature = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


if(!$select_latest_temperature)
{
    echo "DB Connection Error";
    die();
}


// Clear Var to ensure fresh data
unset($latest_temp);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_latest_temperature))
{
    $latest_temp = $row['temperature'];
} 

echo $latest_temp;


?>
```

db-conn.php

```
<?php

//replace with the appropriate values if necessary
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "cl50-iotdb");

//catch errors
if ($connection->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```